# Adobe air import SOL file with FileStream

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I currently have a function that opens up a file browser and limits the selection to the .sol format. I want this function available for easier backwards compatibility support instead of moving the .sol file to the programs appdata folder. When the user selects a .sol, this function is called:

```
public function onSelect_sol(event: Event): void {
        var file: File = File(event.target);
        var fileStream: FileStream = new FileStream();
        fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
        savedData = fileStream.readObject();
        trace(savedData);
        fileStream.close();
    }
```

However the information I get back from the trace is "null". What do I have to do to make it so I can use the information is the sol? I know this can be done, as the minerva sol editor uses adobe air and can open .sol files: http://blog.coursevector.com/minerva

Comment: Although .sol files serialize data in AMF (which `readObject` deserializes) there is still some additional [header and name/value element](http://search.cpan.org/~aff/Parse-Flash-Cookie-0.08/lib/Parse/Flash/Cookie.pm) data you have to parse yourself.

Comment: Also try having a load complete `eventListener` for fileStream. When fully loaded only then do you `trace` an object and close. Those lines of code will run faster than accessing your storage for file data so you trace something not even loaded yet (null). Also you `READ` file bytes **but into where**? Make and upload a test SOL file and _hopefully_ I can edit your code to trace it...